# How can I render a Lit Element Web component using Typescript Express App?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsc, lit-element

I have created a Typescript Express Server:

src/server.ts

```
    import express from "express";

    import { HomeController } from "./controllers";

    const app: express.Application = express();
    const port: number = ((process.env.PORT as any) as number) || 3000;

    app.use(express.static("static"));

    app.use("/", HomeController);

    app.listen(port, () => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
    });
```

src/controllers/index.ts

```
    import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";

    const router: Router = Router();

    router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.send("Hello World");
    });

    export const HomeController: Router = router;
```

structure

```
    ├───build
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───components
    │   └───controllers
    ├───src
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───components
    │   └───controllers
    └───static
        └───images
```

I have tried hosting a static file. Ex. index.html. via `res.send('index.html');` The file is rendered but I am unable to import the element using a script tag.  As the error returned is `Exports is not defined`

src/components/card.ts

```
    import { html, LitElement } from "lit-element";

    class Card extends LitElement {
      protected render() {
        return html`
          <img src="../../static/images/AS.png" />
        `;
      }
    }

    declare global {
      interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
        "card-element": Card;
      }
    }

    customElements.define("card-element", Card);
```

I am using TSC to build my application. I manually copied my static folder into by build folder to use. Im not sure if there is an automatic way to copy this folder on build.

Is there something that I am doing wrong with my compiler that may be giving me the error `Exports is not defined` research says its something to do with CommonJs but I tried installing and the result didnt change

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["./modules"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a module system to bundle or load the JS code.

Comment: @SLaks Bundling with webpack or browserify will work then?

Comment: How are you importing your element into your html? You probably need to add a `type="module"` into it, bundling is only absolutely necessary for compatibility with browsers that don't support modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by bundling my code using webpack. This allowed me to create an Index.html importing my bundle.js file

Comment: Do you have example or source code I am trying to do the same.